# How can I apply aggregate on array of objects?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have this complicated data in MongoDB, I want to reconstruct it into something like the second JSON, I tried both MongoDB aggregate and javascript spread, but I couldn't figure it out.

Original Data

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "61ff24b2db73094dd3029c7e",
    "TeamName": "GoodTeam",
    "TeamImage": "Avatar",
    "TeamMember": [
      {
        "name": "Aimee",
        "image": "https://i.imgur.com/HeIi0wU.png",
        "email": "test2@gmail.com",
        "timezone": "PST",
        "_id": "61ff25fcd2a0b9e13ee8989c"
      },
      {
        "name": "Kai",
        "image": "https://i.imgur.com/HeIi0wU.png",
        "email": "school021195@gmail.com",
        "timezone": "PST",
        "_id": "61ff3114d3d343bd673f5ad3"
      },
      {
        "name": "Iren",
        "image": "https://i.imgur.com/HeIi0wU.png",
        "email": "test1@gmail.com",
        "timezone": "AKST",
        "_id": "61ff3114d3d343bd673f5ad4"
      }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2022-02-06T01:30:26.893Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-02-06T02:23:16.660Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

Reconstruct Data

```json
[
  { 
    "timezone":"PST",
    "TeamMember":[
       {
        "name": "Aimee",
        "image": "https://i.imgur.com/HeIi0wU.png",
        "email": "test2@gmail.com",
        "timezone": "PST",
        "_id": "61ff25fcd2a0b9e13ee8989c"
      },
      {
        "name": "Kai",
        "image": "https://i.imgur.com/HeIi0wU.png",
        "email": "school021195@gmail.com",
        "timezone": "PST",
        "_id": "61ff3114d3d343bd673f5ad3"
      },
  {
    "timezone":"AKST",
    "TeamMember":[
      {
        "name": "Iren",
        "image": "https://i.imgur.com/HeIi0wU.png",
        "email": "test1@gmail.com",
        "timezone": "AKST",
        "_id": "61ff3114d3d343bd673f5ad4"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And how should I deal with this kind of data reconstruction in the front-end or back-end? Which one is better practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a custom transformer for converting one JSON to another JSON and I would suggest you to let the back-end handle this responsibility.

Below is one example using Javascript.

```js
const firstJson = `[
    {
      "_id": "61ff24b2db73094dd3029c7e",
      "TeamName": "GoodTeam",
      "TeamImage": "Avatar",
      "TeamMember": [
        {
          "name": "Aimee",
          "image": "https://i.imgur.com/HeIi0wU.png",
          "email": "test2@gmail.com",
          "timezone": "PST",
          "_id": "61ff25fcd2a0b9e13ee8989c"
        },
        {
          "name": "Kai",
          "image": "https://i.imgur.com/HeIi0wU.png",
          "email": "school021195@gmail.com",
          "timezone": "PST",
          "_id": "61ff3114d3d343bd673f5ad3"
        },
        {
          "name": "Iren",
          "image": "https://i.imgur.com/HeIi0wU.png",
          "email": "test1@gmail.com",
          "timezone": "AKST",
          "_id": "61ff3114d3d343bd673f5ad4"
        }
      ],
      "createdAt": "2022-02-06T01:30:26.893Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-02-06T02:23:16.660Z",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]`;

  const firstJsonObj = JSON.parse(firstJson);
  
  const map = new Map();
  for(let i =0;i<firstJsonObj.length;i++){
    for(let j =0;j<firstJsonObj[i].TeamMember.length;j++){
        let timezone = firstJsonObj[i].TeamMember[j].timezone;
        if(map.has(timezone)){
            const team = map.get(timezone);
            team.push(firstJsonObj[i].TeamMember[j]);
            map.set(timezone,team);
        }
        else{
            map.set(timezone,[firstJsonObj[i].TeamMember[j]])
        }
    }
  }

  const secondJson = Array.from(map,function(element){
      const [key,value] = element;
   return {
        timezone : key,
        TeamMember : value
    }
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(secondJson));
```

**EDIT:**
If you want query data from mongodb itself you can use below query to get the output

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$TeamMember"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "timezone": "$TeamMember.timezone"
      },
      "TeamMember": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT.TeamMember"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "timezone": "$_id.timezone",
      "TeamMember": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: This does work ,thank you very much, but do you think it's capable to use mongoDB aggregate for this? I have been tryin for server hours, still can't  answer, it seems good practice to use query instead of using Javascript to deal with it right ?

Comment: @Kai021195 I have edited the answer, if you want to query this output from MongoDB you can use the above query.

Comment: @Asu Thank you so much! I wonder how do you learn aggregate ? The example on MongoDB is kind of ambiguous for me, is their a way or resource to learn this to do advanced query ?

Answer (score 1):

It is better to do it in the backend and recommended.

You can achieve this by multiple ways in the backend using mongo aggregation framework. It is very powerful framework with multiple operators to handle these kind of data.